# Android : Spinner inside TabView Fragment replaces Tabs when implementing

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am trying to put a Spinner inside one of three tab in TabView. Spinner replaces all the tabs and I see only Spinner in screen.

If I remove method `setSpinnerContent(view)` in `onCreateView` in **FacultyTab.java**, Tabs are visible.

Here is code that I used to implement both Spinner and TabView (Suggestions are appriciated for TabView) :

**MainPage.java** (All tabs gets implemented here)

```
public class MainPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        adapter.addFragment(new NoticeTab(), "Notices");
        adapter.addFragment(new FacultyTab(), "Faculties");
        adapter.addFragment(new StudentCornerTab(), "Student Corner");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

**main_page.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.collegecommune.MainPage">



    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**FacultyTab.java**

```
public class FacultyTab extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    public FacultyTab() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {}

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.faculty_tab, container, false);
        setSpinnerContent(view);

        return view;
    }

    public void setSpinnerContent(View view) {

        getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.faculty_tab);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
                R.array.faculty_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
}
```

**faculty_tab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/faculty_array"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Adapter.java**

```
public class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Adapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

First I was getting some runtime errors while implementing Spinner, but after searching in Stackoverflow, I removed errors but now this problem is happening.

Note: I am beginner in Android. I couldn't find way to implement TabView, so I copied it and Edited some part of it. Suggestions for Implementing TabView better way will help a lot too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove this line,

```
getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.faculty_tab);
```

setContentView will set the `R.layout.faculty_tab` as your main page view. Not the tab's view

Comment: I kinda feel stupid. But well it worked. Any suggestions for implementation of TabLayout?

Comment: [this link](https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/) will help you.